# database for log analysis application in java - 2014

Tags: java, mongodb, hbase, log-analysis, database

I want to create a java application for the purpose of handling and analyzing **live streaming logs**. I have to implement some complex filter functionality also. I was doing a research on finding the best suited database for the same.

I came across many portable database like **mongodb**, **hbase**, **h2** and all. Among all, mongodb seems to be a better candidate. But for my requirement, there may be *insertion and selection* happening at the same time. Somewhere I read like, **mongodb** is not best *at handling concurrency*.

I'm sure, moving forward the performance of database is going to play a crucial role in the whole performance of the application.
I came across many stack overflow links regarding the same. But the thing is, all of them are *asked 2 or more years back*. 
Can mongodb handle concurrency? Is there any other portable database which is better than mongodb for the same?
Please help.

Comment: why are you only considering in memory dbs ? what's reason for not using a relational db like postgres, mysql or oracle, mssql which have full ACID support ?

Comment: i want to create a standalone application. for using mysql db, there should be a mysql server installed, right? A simple portable database, like sqlite is what I was searching for. If I'm wrong, pls correct me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to some solution, for instance, like elasticsearch coupled with kibana and td-agent?

It provides asynchronous logging. I've used it to store and analyze 30 millions events per day from several servers, but it depends what you want to do in the end.

Comment: for logging and filtering  elasticsearch coupled with kibana is the best approach.only there is some latency but not much of getting latest log but that acceptable

Comment: yes. it seems to be a good solution. But I want to develop a stand alone application in java for the same purpose.

Comment: @ArunPaul Both Elasticsearch and Kibana are written in Java already. Is it Java that you need or to write it yourself? In any case, their code are open sourced, so just take a look at it.